# How to display selectable field values for query parameters in Swagger UI

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-ui

I'm working on a project where I'm using Swagger UI to document and test my API endpoints. I've encountered a challenge that I hope to get some guidance on.

**Issue:**

I need to display a list of selectable field values for a specific query parameter in Swagger UI. This is crucial for enhancing the usability of the API documentation, especially for users who are not familiar with the database schema.

**Example:**

Consider the following API endpoint:

```
http://localhost:8000/food/event.json?search=products.industry_name:"Soft+Drink/Water"+AND+reactions.exact:DEHYDRATION&limit=10
```

In this case, search is a query parameter. However, the values it can take, like `products.industry_name` and `reactions.exact`, are specific field names within the search query.

**What I want to achieve:**

I would like Swagger UI to provide a dropdown or a list of these field names (`products.industry_name`, `reactions.exact`, etc.) so that users can easily select them without having to know them in advance.

**Current approach:**

I've tried looking into Swagger's documentation but couldn't find a straightforward way to implement this. Most examples and resources I've found deal with standard parameter enumeration, which doesn't quite fit this use case.

**Question:**

1. How can I configure Swagger UI to allow users to select from a predefined list of field names for a query parameter?
2. Is there a way to dynamically populate this list based on the database schema or should it be statically defined?

Any pointers, code snippets, or references to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated. I'm open to alternative approaches as well if there's a better way to achieve this functionality.